# Saving Map on Server Side as Image File

Tags: openlayers-2, printing, image, jpg

I am trying to save my openlayers map on the server, following these instructions, the sections `Client-side: Tile collection` and `Server side: PHP`:

http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/wiki/TileStitchingPrinting

On the server side, the script creates lots of tiles-files, with names like `6910a8c32e7e8e4e81270bba8a106231.img`, and, finally, an jpg file , `3696d338f25f6a64ea6f90a78b3276b9.jpg`, that is supposed to be the image of the maps. However, the content of this file is only black, whatever the content of the map might have been.

Any ideas?

Comment: Still not solved at all. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution by replacing the function `imagecopymerge_alpha` given in http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/wiki/TileStitchingPrinting by the following function:

```
function imagecopymerge_alpha($dst_im, $src_im, $dst_x, $dst_y, $src_x, $src_y, $src_w, $src_h, $pct) {

  // creating a cut resource
  $cut = imagecreatetruecolor($src_w, $src_h);

  // copying relevant section from background to the cut resource
  imagecopy($cut, $dst_im, 0, 0, $dst_x, $dst_y, $src_w, $src_h);

  // copying relevant section from watermark to the cut resource
  imagecopy($cut, $src_im, 0, 0, $src_x, $src_y, $src_w, $src_h);

  // insert cut resource to destination image
  imagecopymerge($dst_im, $cut, $dst_x, $dst_y, 0, 0, $src_w, $src_h, $pct);

}
```

Comment: However, it still only prints the WMS Layer, not any WFS Layer.

Comment: WFS serves vector data, so if your input data is raster data, it's not going to work.